# Print output log using more digits

Tags: python, pyomo, gurobi

I am creating plots of the evolution of the upper and lower bound of  the objective function for a MILP, where I use gurobi to generate these.

When I create a logfile, either .log, .txt or .csv, it seems that values are rounded to 4 decimals in the file, and that I cannot retrieve the original values (only from the Python console directly). Is there a way to print these in a logfile with more decimals? My model is programmed in Pyomo.

Best regards.

```
     Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work

 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time


0 0 2.5500e+08 0 194 3.2154e+08 2.5500e+08 20.7% - 1s

0 0 2.5502e+08 0 193 3.2154e+08 2.5502e+08 20.7% - 1s
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered over in the [official Gurobi community forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360062623072-More-digits-in-log-file):

> There unfortunately isn't a way to increase the log precision like this. However, you can retrieve these lower and upper bounds programmatically with the `MIPNODE_OBJBST` and `MIPNODE_OBJBND` callbacks (see [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cb_codes.html)). This should make plotting much easier, since you won't have to spend time extracting these values from the log. Pyomo is a third-party API, but I believe they support callbacks like this.